# Creating multiple tables with identical columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm new to PL/SQL. Is it possible to create a given number of tables with identical columns but specific table names inside a while (or for) loop setting the individual table names with the help of string concatenation e.g. No_1, No_2, etc?

My attempt:

```
DECLARE
  my_num  integer := 1;
  conc char(1);
BEGIN
  WHILE my_num <= 5 LOOP
    select to_char(my_num) into conc from dual;

    Create table No_||conc (dists float);
    my_num :=my_num+1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

It does not work. I would be grateful if someone could make this clear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `execute immediate` statement to run DDL inside a PL/SQL block, like this:

```
DECLARE
  my_num  integer := 1;
  conc char(1);
BEGIN
  WHILE my_num <= 5 LOOP

    execute immediate 'create table No_' || my_num || ' (dists float)';

    my_num :=my_num+1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

However, I want to point out that Oracle discourages the use of `integer` and `float` (in favor of `number`), and `char` in favor of `varchar2`. And I think your code would be more commonly written like this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR my_num in 1..5 LOOP
    execute immediate 'create table No_' || my_num || ' (dists number)';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! Have a nice day!